# while using webpack devserver, express session is not persistence in appl server

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Am using below things in my learning project...
1) React/redux,node,express as app server which handled server side user login(runs in 3000 port)
2)Using ES6 in my both server and UI(react),
3)using webpack(in prot 8080) generate es5 bundle for my developement activity.

in my app server, i have set simple seesion to after user auth

```
    router.post('/signin', reqAdminCredentials, (req, res) => {
    const userName = req.body.userName;
    const password = req.body.password;

    res.json(auth.getToken(userName));
     .then((isLoginSuccess) => {
         req.session.user = userName;
         res.json({ loginSuccess: true })
    })
     .catch(e => {
         res.status(500).json({ error: "LOGIN_FAILS" });
     })
});
```

and here is my webpack config

```
   entry: [
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    `webpack-dev-server/client?${HOST_URI}`,
    './public/index.js'
],
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devtool: 'source-map',
module: {
    loaders: [{
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
    },
    { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
    {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: SRC
    },
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 3000
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    // Define the env
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
            'SECONDS': JSON.stringify(SECONDS),
            'QUESTIONCOUNT': JSON.stringify(QUESTIONCOUNT)

        }
    }),
    // Build progress bar
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(function(percentage, msg) {
        console.log((percentage * 100) + '%', msg);
    })
],
```

};

but am always getting 'req.session.user' as 'undefiend', if tried to get req.session.user in next successive request

```
 router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    req.session.count = 0;
    res.json(`user:${req.session.user} count:${req.session.count}`);
});
```

kindly help me on this

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: Hey, did you ever get this working? (cc @zehelvion)